# Calculating Theta scores for identified subjects (using R package ltm)

Tags: r, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I am using the R package *ltm* to calculate a 2PL IRT model.

**goal:**
creating a list of subjects IDs with the calculated Theta scores.

**problem:** *ltm* requires that the input includes only item scores, and does not permit to include subject identifiers.

Thus, i have to exclude the first variable in the data which is the id number

```
fit2PL <- ltm(ScoreData[2:100] ~ z1)
```

**questions:**

1. How can I rematch the identifiers and the claculated scores? Can I
   be sure the ltm doesnt change the order of subjects (i.e. the the
   unidentifed theta scores it outputs are ordered the same as the
   input item scores?).
2. alternatively, can i use a formula to calculate theta scores for each subject, using
   individual item scores and the models parameters for each item?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so it seems that there's no option in package *ltm* to calculate subject theta estimates.
It is possible however using package *mirt*.

```
library(mirt)
data[,101] <- fscores(mirt(ScoreData[2:100], 1,itemtype='2PL'))
colnames(data)[101]  <- "Theta scores"
```